# How to add multi-threading/multi-client feature to a very simple scala server program?

Tags: multithreading, scala

scala newbie here,

I'm deliberately using an older version of `scala 2.7.5`

This is for compatibilites for older libraries i need to use along with this server code

```
val server = new ServerSocket(9999)
println("Server initialized:")
val client = server.accept

/* Initalize a big service here -> takes >10 seconds */


while(true){

  val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream)).readLine
  val out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream)

  println("Server received:" + in)
  out.println("Message received")
  out.flush
}
```

Basically, this works from a single client. But it won't connect from another client because it will always be running inside the `while` loop

I need to modify the code to process requests from multiple clients

Therefore, is it possible for me to do so without writing a multithreaded program?

if not, can anyone help me out with a code snippet to add basic threading to this program?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use NIO `Channels` in non-blocking mode - this will let you multiplex several input streams using a single thread.  [This is a tutorial in the NIO SocketChannel](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socketchannel.html) along with an explanation of how to switch it to non-blocking mode, and [this is a tutorial on using Selectors](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html) from the same author.  The [SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) is what you'll use to read the sockets, and the [Selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) is what you'll use to multiplex the channels.

From the tutorial linked above:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("http://jenkov.com", 80));
while(! socketChannel.finishConnect() ){
  //wait, or do something else...    
}
```

Calling `read` on a non-blocking `SocketChannel` might return zero bytes, so check to see how many bytes were returned.

As for the `Selector` (again from the tutorial)

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();
// OP_READ means that the Selector is interested in read events
SelectionKey key1 = socketChannel1.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
SelectionKey key2 = socketChannel2.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
    SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
    if (key.isReadable()) {
        // read from the channel
    }
}
```